# Why are these floating divs not displaying properly?

Tags: html

I'm trying to create two floating divs inside of another:

```
 <div style="width:100%;height:500px;position:relative;top:15px;">          

        <div style="position:relative;float:left;width:58%;height:100%;left:10px;">
            <div id="borderdiv" style="position:relative;width:92%;top:20px;bottom:20px;left:20px;border:1px solid #000;background-color:gray;">
                <div style="height:30px;text-align:center;position:relative;    "><h2>welcome</h2></div>                
                <div style="position:relative;width:25%;background-color:green;float:left;">floating div1</div>
                <div style="position:relative;width:25%;background-color:red;float:left;">floating div2</div>               
            </div>
        </div>


   </div>
```

The problem is the floating div1 and div2 are outside the border of the div with id "borderdiv". What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Floated elements have no height, so `#borderdiv` does not expand to contain them.

You can use a clearing element to correct this:

```
<div style="position:relative;width:25%;background-color:red;float:left;">floating div2</div>
<div style="clear: both" />
```

[Demo on JSFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/eKBeG/)

Answer (score 1):

Since your question was not very specific, then my answer is very simple. This simply puts the div1 and div2 inside the borderdiv:

```
<div style="width:100%;height:500px;position:relative;top:15px;">          
    <div style="position:relative;float:left;width:58%;height:100%;left:10px;">
        <div id="borderdiv" style="position:relative;width:92%;top:20px;bottom:20px;left:20px;border:1px solid #000;background-color:gray;">
            <div style="position:relative;width:25%;background-color:green;float:left;">floating div1</div>
            <div style="position:relative;width:25%;background-color:red;float:left;">floating div2</div>               
            <div style="height:30px;text-align:center;position:relative;"><h2>welcome</h2></div>    
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: George Cummins answer is actually better. But based on the specifications of the question, I wont delete my answer.